# Android How To Create Multiple Alarms AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alarms

Hi I am trying to create multiple alarms.
I am getting the number of hours left in the day, dividing it by the number of alarms needed, then trying to set alarms with intervals between them.

So for example if num of alarms is 2, and user clicks button at 14:00 there are 10 hours left, so 10 hours / 2 alarms = 5 hours distance between each alarm

So I want to set 2 alarms (one alarm at 19:00 and another at 24:00)

**Currently my code is only setting 1 alarm and seems to ignore running the for loop multiple times. I'm not sure why the for loop dosnt create multiple alarms**

```
        try {
            // Current Time
            Time timeNow = new Time();
            timeNow.setToNow();
                int timeNowHour = timeNow.hour;
                int timeNowMins = timeNow.minute;

            // Hours left in day
                int hoursInADay = 24;
                int hoursLeftInDay = hoursInADay - timeNowHour;

            // Number of alarms
                int numAlarms = 2;

            // Calc time between each alarm
                int alarmDistance = hoursLeftInDay / numAlarms;

            for(int i = 0; i < numAlarms; i++){
                int alarmHour = timeNowHour + alarmDistance * (i+1);
                Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
                alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "TEST ALARM");
                alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, alarmHour);
                alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, timeNowMins);
                alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
                alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(alarmIntent);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: try using the alarm manager...

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to understand why the alarmIntent does not execute twice in the for loop?

Comment: @user2511882 do I need to assign a id or something to the intent to make it run multiple times in the for loop?

Comment: I never tried using an intent. And besides alarm manager is much easier to use. I can write up something if you want

Comment: @user2511882 I solved the problem using a post delayed handler, thank you for the help.

Comment: @user2511882 Its not working again.
All the examples I found using AlarmManager have a additional receiver class, is there a simple way to user AlarmManager to set alarms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AlarmManager alarmManager= (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent intent=createPendingResult(ALARM_TIME_ID, new Intent(), 0);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + alarmDistance,alarmDistance, intent);
```

And in the onActivityMethod you can do whatever you want.
Example:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == ALARM_TIME_ID) {
Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Make sure to set the `ALARM_TIME_ID` to a unique `int` value.

Comment: Thanks. Would this set an alarm in the alarm application? (the intent way sets an actual alarm)
or is this to perform certain actions when the pending intent time is reached? such as opening an activity

Comment: Yes.. this should setup an alarm for you

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately I couldn't get this to work. I used the first block of code, then checked my list of alarms and it has not created a new one.

Comment: you need to use the onACtivityResult as well. Put the first block in the onCreate and use the onActivityResult as-is. You should see toast poping up for whatever the time duration is..